# Using Yolo in Unity's Virtual Environment or Using any OR model in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, yolo, object-recognition, barracuda

I cannot find any material or resource related to connecting Yolo Models to Unity, I know that unity has Barracuda package which allows the using of Tiny yolov2, does anyone know how can I use it, or whether if I can use yolov4/v5 within unity.

My purpose for this to recognize objects within my virtual scene using a CNN model.

I have tried an outdated source however it didn't work at all (as expected).